# How to store Collection.reverse back into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

My issue is I am trying to reverse an array. The method I have found that apparently works for this is to use

```
 Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arrx));
```

However I want to store it back into an array for future use. 
I'm not quite familiar with Collections to begin with, I did go over the documentation for it however in terms of storing this back into an array i'm a little lost. 
How would you go about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Collections.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()) is your friend. It has two methods a type safe and a non type safe one (preferred to use type safe).

```
    Integer[] a = new Integer[] {1,2,3};
    List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(a);
    Collections.reverse(l);
    l.toArray(a);
```

If possible using Collections instead of arrays is the best practice.

Comment: `#toArray()` is not necessary in this case. The JavaDoc on `Arrays#asList` says: "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.  **(Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)**".

Comment: @qqilihq but still the question was about "I want to store it back into an array for future use".

Comment: @Aivean Still, one should point out, that the original array is modified (and obviously this was not clear to the author of the question).

Comment: @qqilihq In the example above, user2961971 wants to reverse the array (with the same size). You are right in other cases we have to check the size of the Collections, and create an array with that fixed size.

Comment: @qqilihq I linked the documentation of toArray()s. We couldn't thinking in place of the questioner.

Comment: @qqilihq ah, you meant that `ArrayList` returned by `asList` will use the initial array and `reverse` will thus modify the initial array. Clever.

Comment: @Aivean Exactly. Tried to make it clear in an alternative answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following consideration is slightly academic, however I felt that it should be pointed out:

`Arrays#asList` will give you a **"view"** on the supplied array. The JavaDoc says: "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. **(Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)**". Looking at your example:

```
String[] arrx = {"alpha", "beta", "gamma"};
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arrx));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrx)); // [gamma, beta, alpha]
```

... this means, that the original array `arrx` will be reversed. If you just need the reversed array, all is fine. However: If you still need the original array, create a copy before reversing:

```
String[] arrx = {"alpha", "beta", "gamma"};
List temp = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arrx));
Collections.reverse(temp);
Object[] reversedArrx = temp.toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrx)); // [alpha, beta, gamma]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reversedArrx)); // [gamma, beta, alpha]
```

(Generics omitted for brevity).

Answer (score -1):

And what about a for loop ? it would be like:

```
static void reverse(int[] t){
  for(int x=0; x<t.length / 2; x++){
    int y = t[x];
    t[x] = t[t.length - 1 - x];
    t[t.length - 1 - x] = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: My Java compiler gives me multiple errors when I try this.

Comment: @ajb yes, it's not Java, but you got the idea.

Comment: Normally if someone asks a question about Java, and only Java, and has the `java` tag on the question, answering in another language is not appropriate.  And it doesn't answer the question anyway.  He wanted to know how to reverse an array using the `reverse` method already available in Java, not a general algorithm for reversing an array.

Comment: @ajb the OP asks for a way to reverse an array. Transforming it to a list is totally inefficient.